# Forming right triangle with given hypotenuse and angles

Tags: geometry, coordinates

I have two points A=[ax,ay] and B=[bx,by] and i have angle in right triangle for CAB, for CBA (thats 90-ACB) and for ACB (90, right angle). Now i want to get coordinates [cx,cy] of point C (from two possibilities, i want that one C point which lies to left of orientated line segment form A to B).

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate middle point D=(A+B)/2
2. Rotate vector DB on angle 2*CAB

(this is based on facts that centre of circumscribed circle is the middle of hypotenuse and that angle from centre is twice angle from A)

let's B-D=(dx,dy)

then C=D+(dx*cos2a+dy*sin2a,dy*cos2a-dx*sin2a)

Comment: Good one. Forgot about the Thales' circle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're given a side and two adjanced angles, what's left is to construct the the lines for the other two sides and intersect them.

Rotate the vector `A->B` by the angle `BAC` to the left, rotate the vector `B->A` by the angle `ABC` to the right and intersect.

To rotate a vector to the left, multiply it by the rotation matrix:

```
 cos(a) sin(a)
-sin(a) cos(a)
```

To intersect two lines in their parametric forms in 2D, solve both parameters simultaneously, comparing the two components for both lines.

Comment: @JanDvorak, were you going to come back? ^^,

Comment: @Swivelgames I was, but then Maxim1000 reminded me I forgot about the Thales` circle, so I upvoted his answer instead. Should I work out mine anyways?